# Odd behaviour noticed with Gmail on different browsers

Tags: gmail, javascript, google-talk, mac

So I have my Gmail account open on two different browsers on the same computer (Chrome and Firefox). Now I was using the pop out chat feature of [Google Talk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Talk) embedded in the web page of my Chrome browser.

If I close the chat box inside Firefox (which I did not pop out), the chat window which I had popped out of my Chrome browser closes too!

Why is this happening? (I am using a Ubuntu 10.04 running on a MackBook)

Answer (score 1):

If GTalk works the same as Live Messenger, when you close a conversation in one place, it closes it everywhere.  Do you observe the same behavior if you try it the other way, and close the conversation from chrome while Firefox also has the conversation open?

Comment: yes, it closes it too! I was wondering if you were aware what script they are running to make this happen?

Comment: It's the same with the conversations, if you write something in one window/browser, it will appear in the other as well.